# Rails persistent "No template for interactive request" although the template exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had this issue with rails. I have followed the basic guide:

`rails new blog-2`

`rails g controller Homepage index`

So now I have the standard folder with all the files, plus the controller `Homepage` and `index.html.erb` in `view/homepage` folder

Next I changed the routes to

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'homepage#index'
end
```

[This is how my directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h90GY.png)

I did not edit the `homepage_controller.rb` nor the `index.html.erb`

[But I keep getting this error at localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnoVY.png)

I have tried many ways, uninstall everything, reinstall. Desperate me, I even reset my laptop. Install everything again, but to no avail. Master railers, please help, thank you!!

Edit:
Here's my index action as per requested

```rb
class HomepageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Edit:
below is the error when I run `rails s`

```sh
Processing by HomepageController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1996)



ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (HomepageController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html):

actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:45:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in 
send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'     
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'     
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'        
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument' 
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'        
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:17:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'    
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:277:in `context'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:271:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'   
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'     
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'      
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'     
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.1.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'   
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: what's inside your `index` action? can you add that to the question?

Comment: Can you post the code of the index action. Looking at your directory structure all should work out fine

Comment: Added index action to the question

Comment: Accordingly to your paths and code everything should work fine, I can't reproduce your error with your code

Comment: Would you mind to post your rails and ruby version? if you don't know how to check a version, type in termial like `$ rails -v ; ruby -v

Comment: `Rails 6.0.2.1` and `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]` @ogelacinyc

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem on Windows 10, and I found a solution finally. I was using **gitbash** to navigate to the project folder and run `rails s`. After try everything I read on the internet (rebooting computer, reinstalling rails, rolling back to previous versions, reconfiguring routes, renaming html.erb files...), I still faced the same problem.

One day, I decided to run `rails s` on **Windows CMD** and voila it got fixed! All my code -  controllers, index.html.erb files etc are all exactly the same.

Comment: In my case I was using Powershell, switch to windows CMD and worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

updated

I have test same envirionments like your description.

rails 6.0.2.1

ruby 2.6.5

windows10 and mac 10.14.6

But I failed to reproduce error.

It was only causes by typing miss for directory or file

Check your directories and files whether it contains whitespace

---

*rename view/homepage to views/homepage
`view` doens't recognize in rails
rails has default type of directory naming by plural*

Comment: hi thanks for the input, but the folder is already `views` from the start

Comment: ok, you should change  view/homepage which misspelled directory path in your post.

Comment: I have tried with both `view` and `views`, both didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i was having this same issue with a rails app initialized today. turns out that my html.erb files were going into my layouts directory inside my views directory. i moved everything that was inside my layouts directory up a level (so everything that was in layouts is now a direct descendant of the 'views' directory) and my app was working again. i didn't see anything about moving the directories in the [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.0.2) but maybe it's a new feature. anyway, hope this helps!

edit: looks like the application.html.erb needs to remain inside of the layouts directory (and i'm guessing then so should the mailer.html.erb & mailer.text.erb files) for the app to load properly. but for controllers to find their respective html.erb files they should still be in directories directly beneath 'views'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Windows 10 & same versions of Ruby and Rails), and it appears that I had created my project in a linked directory (it was `c:\Local\myproject`, but "Local" was a link):
[image: screenshot]

When I create the project from the root, for example `c:\Projects\myproject`, everything works fine... Or another solution is to launch `rails server` from the full path `c:\users\PUBLIC\Documents\myproject`.